# How to enable special characters in moc?

Tags: shell

I am using [moc](http://moc.daper.net/) ([what is moc](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/MOC_-_music_on_console)) on Mac OS X 10.9 in zsh shell. I want to enable special German characters like ä, ü, ö and ß for it. How can I enable such characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install moc with the option `--with-ncurses`. When you use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) you can do the following:

```
brew uninstall moc
brew cleanup
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install moc --with-ncurses
```

This enables moc to display a lot of special characters including the german "Umlaute" and "ß".